# "require: cannot load such file -- mach" with when installing opam with Homebrew

Tags: ruby, homebrew, opam

I am trying to install OPAM with the ultimate goal of installing OCAML. I tried to run

```
brew install OPAM
```

and I got this error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mach (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

so then i tried updating brew

```
brew update
```

and got this

```
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 file2
   install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
   install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
```

It seems like just about anything I do with brew is giving me problems. It seems like something is wrong with ruby.

If i do

```
ruby -v
```

I get

```
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

Any help here is appreciated

PS I tried running sudo on these and got the same error

Comment: Please use a clear title, not "crazy issue"; it doesn’t help anyone answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

try uninstalling and reinstalling brew

https://github.com/homebrew/install